# Cakephp 3 - public function add doesn't work with isAuthorized

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.0

I have a little problem with the isAuthorized function.

When I use the public function **add**, isAuthorized doesn't recognize the action request. I changed the name to '**addv**' and now it's working. So why? Why can't I use the word 'add'? I used it twice on another project and I used it once on my current project.

Thanks you for you help !

```
<?php  
namespace App\Controller;       

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class VideosController extends AppController{

    public function isAuthorized($user){
        if(in_array($this->request->action, ['addv'])){
            die();
            if($user){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }

    public function addv($idc= null,$idg = null){
        debug($idc);
        debug($this->request->action);
    }


}
?>
```

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');

    $this->set('info_session', $this->Auth->user());
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->Auth->allow(['register']);
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    $this->Auth->allow(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']);


}

public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['grade']) && $user['grade']=== 3){
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your `AppController` code to the question.

Comment: AppController added :)

Comment: You are allowing the add action to be accessed by everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp 3.0 isAuthorized() not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234682/cakephp-3-0-isauthorized-not-being-called)